# Is there an efficient way to find the first n duplicates in a series?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to identify

- the **first 6 elements of an array which are greater than 5**,
- and then the next 6 consecutive elements which are less than 5.
- The number of elements in between these two spans is my desired
  output.

I have done a similar problem in the past where I needed to find the longest length of **consecutive values** `>n` and used `np.where` to convert my series into a binary array, then found the maximum consecutive value. 
I tried to use a similar method but it wasn't very fruitful, though I am sticking with a binary array since I think it will be the simplest way to handle things. `df` is my **array**, and `n` is the **length** of the array.

```py
def first_six_dupes(df, n):

   for i in (5, n-1):

      if df[i-5] == 1 and df[i-4] == 1 and df[i-3] == 1 and df[i-2] == 1 and df[i-1] == 1 and df[i] == 1:

         return i
```

This returns "`None`" when I print the output. If I ask it to just find a single index that **equal to 1**(`index==1`), it returns the very last index rather than the first occurrence. I don't get any errors. 
My expected result would be the last index of the first six consecutive "`1`" digits in my binary array. For example, if my array were `[0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]` I'd expect to get `9` as a returned value.

Comment: you're asking if the element is equal to 1, should ask if equal to `i`

Answer (score 1):

***MCVE***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [6,7,8,9,9,9,2,2,1,1,6,2,2,2,2,2,3]})
```

---

IIUC, You can groupby consecutive values and use `cumsum` to find these regions between spans of consecutive values meeting your criteria.

```
def elements_between_runs(series, threshold, runs):
    m = series.gt(threshold)
    g = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()
    f = m.groupby(g).cumsum().eq(runs).idxmax()
    l = (~m).groupby(g).cumsum().eq(runs).idxmax()
    if l > f:
        return l - f - runs
    else:
        raise ValueError('No region found matching criteria')
```

---

```
>>> elements_between_runs(df.col1, threshold=5, runs=6)
5

>>> elements_between_runs(df.col1, threshold=5, runs=7)
ValueError: No region found matching criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make a new column called 'check' where the value is 1 if it's above 5, and 0 if its <= 5.

```
df['check'] = np.where(df['col'] > 5, 1,0)
```

This will make another new column called 'repeat' where you can see how many times in a row it will be <= or > 5.

```
df['repeat'] =  df['check'].groupby((df['check'] != df['check'].shift()).cumsum()).transform('count')
```

Finally we can filter to find the groups that are larger than 6. You can also filter by 'check' to get only the ones less than or greater than 5.

```
df[df.groupby('repeat')['repeat'].transform('size')>=6]
```